# How to set-up Xubuntu to show Applications menu on desktop right-click?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

As far as I know, in older versions of XFCE this was a default behaviour - "Applications" menu was popped-up immediately on desktop mouse right-click. But now "Applications" menu appears as a sub-menu in a folder-class context menu which pops up instead.

I never store any files on the Desktop, so "Create folder", "Open terminal here" menu items are useless for me to have on the Desktop, instead I'd like "Applications" menu to open when I right-click on the Desktop.

From using ArchLinux I can remember that there was a special package to install to address this issue. Is there such a package (or another solution) available for Xubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to disable all desktop icons in the `Desktop` configuration dialog in the `Icons` section. This will make the Application menu your right-click menu.

Unfortunately you can't have both.

Comment: That was one the first things I've done after installation - I don't use any desktop icons. But as I can see now, it was not enough to uncheck icons' checkboxes - after I also set "Icon type" to none, the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, but where is the right click menu configured? Where is the XML or whatever they use to configure it? - I found it in `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu`